# Single tap working as right click and double tap as single in Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity

Tags: unity, mouse, touchpad, synaptics, multi-touch

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity installed. Mouse was working fine until I updated using apt-get upgrade, after which, single tap opens right click menu. And tapping with two fingers selects the file. Actually pressing the touchpad buttons work fine but taps are switched. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Is the problem persists if you use GNOME instead of Unity?

Comment: It works fine on GNOME. @AryoAdhi

Comment: I have the same problem, how do you installed unity ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package and enable tapping.

Steps:

1. `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`
2. `sudo mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`
3. `sudo touch /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`
4. Add the following config in `40-libinput.conf`

   `Section "InputClass"
       Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
       MatchIsTouchpad "on"
       MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
       Driver "libinput"
       Option "Tapping" "on"
   EndSection`
5. Restart lightdm - `systemctl restart lightdm`

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad